# Create a single tar file for multiple directories by excluding its parent folders

Tags: linux, shell, tar

I'm working on a bash shell script which creates a tar file for multiple folders by excluding its parent folders to all the directories and also exclude specified folder.

The directory structure is:

```
$ ls dir1
dir11 testdir

$ ls dir2
dir12 testdir2

$ ls dir3
dir13 testdir3

$ tar -cvf file1.tar dir1 dir2 dir3 --exclude="test*"
```

The above works fine.

But I dont want the dir1, dir2 and dir3 folders also in tar. I need only inside the files and directories.

So my final tar should contain as following

```
$ tar -tvf file1.tar
dir11 dir12 dir13
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this one. Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I understand right the question, you can use the `-C` (capital C = change directory) option, e.g:

```
tar cvf /tmp/some.tar -C /path/to/dir1 . -C /path/to/dir2 .    #multiple -C allowed
```

check it with

```
 tar cf - -C /path/to/dir1 . -C /path/to/dir2 .  | tar tvf -
```

Example:

createing a testcase

```
cd /tmp
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir -p {dir{1..3},testdir}
touch dir1/file{1..3} dir2/file{4..6} dir3/file{7..9}
```

the tree is now:

```
$ find . -print
.
./dir1
./dir1/file1
./dir1/file2
./dir1/file3
./dir2
./dir2/file4
./dir2/file5
./dir2/file6
./dir3
./dir3/file7
./dir3/file8
./dir3/file9
./testdir
```

The tar:

```
tar cf - -C dir1 . -C ../dir2 . -C ../dir3 . | tar tvf -
```

the tar content is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:07 ./
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:07 ./file1
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:07 ./file2
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:07 ./file3
drwxr-xr-x  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:08 ./
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file4
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file5
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file6
drwxr-xr-x  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:08 ./
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file7
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file8
-rw-r--r--  0 jm    staff       0 14 aug 13:10 ./file9
```

If you want something other, please edit your question.

Comment: NO, I'm unable to do tar. It is throwing error as follows:

Comment: tar: dir2: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: dir3: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: @user27 each chage directory is relative to the actual one.. see the above example... You should to use `../dir2` (from `dir1`) or _use full path names_ as i said in the 1st part of answer.

Comment: The exact output what you have given that's what I need

Comment: @user27 So the answer is correct. ;) enjoy. (and next time, read carefully the recommendation, and it is userful to read the manpage too ;) :)

Comment: Cool, but please specify better that paths should be absolute.

Comment: @ceztko as shown in the test-case, it is possible to use relative paths too, or please, be more specific what is the problem.

Comment: @jm666 one can use relative paths but it is really counter intuitive in the sense one expects that relative paths will be always relative to command invocation directory (it would have been a more sane behavior). The answer could specify the paths in the 1st example are absolute for better readability and quick usability.

Comment: @ceztko yes, the first example in the answer `tar cvf /tmp/some.tar -C /path/to/dir1 . -C /path/to/dir2 .`  using absolute paths. You're correct.

Comment: Is this behavior depending on the exact flavor of tar? I have it working on Ubuntu, but failing on Alpine linux with the exact same line